# How can I install freeGlut for windows on Codeblocks 12.11?

Tags: installation, codeblocks, freeglut

I have never installed new libraries in Codeblocks before and would like to know how to do it, Thank you!

Comment: At first try to do google. Do what you found? if problem occurs then ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

At first download the freeglut from [here](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download). Don't download the source download the binaries. Unzip the zip file then you will see the include directories ,lib directories and greeglut.dll file.
After you download and open the GLUT bin zip file, you will need to:
Copy freeglut32.dll to c:\windows\system,
Copy freeglut32.lib to c:\program files\mingw\lib, and
Copy freeglut.h to c:\program files\mingw\include\GL. 
 All steps I can't explain here So for details please follow this link [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Using_FreeGlut_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks) or this link [here](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~goetz/codeblocks/glut/)